# Would it not be same memory address after this assignment?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *p = NULL ,c , *q;
c=10;
p = &c;
q = p; 

printf ("%d and %d ",&p, &q );
```

Output:

```
2686788 and 2686780
```

My question is: As far I assume, I thought the memory address will be same, as I have assigned `p` into `q`. May be I am wrong.

Comment: `&p` is "address of p". q and p are two entirely different variables, so they have different addresses. What's **AT** those addresses will be the same (address of C).

Comment: Note that the correct format for printing a `void *` address is `%p`, or you can get fine-grained control with `<inttypes.h>` and `uintptr_t` and `PRIXPTR` and related macros.  `%d` on many 64-bit systems (though not 64-bit Windows) will yield bogus results because you invoke undefined behaviour by telling `printf` to treat addresses as integers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`p` and `q` are two different variables and their addresses are different. `&p` and `&q` are addresses of `p` and `q` respectively.
The content of `p` and `q` will be the same, i.e. they will contain the same memory address after the assignment

```
q = p;
```

`p` and `q` both are pointing to the same memory location now. As for the illustration this is shown in the below ASCII art:

```
          p                          
      +-------+                      
      |       |                 c    
0x200 | 0x100 +---------+   +-------+
      |       |         +-> |       |
      +-------+             |  10   |
          q             +-> |       |
      +-------+         |   +-------+
      |       |         |     0x100  
0x300 | 0x100 +---------+            
      |       |                      
      +-------+                      


        p = q but &p != &q
```

---

**NOTE:** To print the pointer data type use `%p` specifier in `printf`.

```
 printf ("%p and %p ", (void *)&p, (void *)&q );
```

Comment: I just wanted the explanation to be like this... Thanks a lot

Comment: @ZahidHossain you should accept an answer that you feel was the most clear to you.

Comment: It should be `printf ("%p and %p ",(void*) &p, (void*) &q )`, as `%p` is defined for `void`-pointers only.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the **content** of variables with their **address**.  In this case the content of both p and q is the address of c.  However, being distinct variables their addresses will always be different.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing the address of the variable, not the address it's pointing to.

Both p and q are pointing to the same address, but are different variables, this way they've different addresses.

i.e:

*c*(address: 1000) -> 10

*p*(address: 1010) -> 1000

*q*(address: 2020) -> 1000

change to this, and you should see the value you want.

```
int *p = NULL ,c , *q;
c=10;
p = &c;
q = p; 

printf ("%p and %p ",p, q );
```

%p prints the address the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Please see my comment on *haccks* answer. The same applies to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address of the pointers themselves, not the pointer values:

```
// Prints the memory location of the pointers
printf ("%d and %d\n", &p, &q);

// Prints the values of the pointers
printf ("%d and %d\n",  p,  q);

// Prints the values that the pointers point to
printf ("%d and %d\n", *p, *q);
```

Comment: Although the answer is correct, the examples miss the necessary accuracy ... - sry 1-.

Comment: @alk - To help me going forward, what sort of additional information do you think should have been included?

Comment: For printing a pointer's value you use the wrong conversion specifier.